# Import CSV data from S3 to Dynamodb using Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I want to Import CSV data from S3 to Dynamodb using Lambda Can I do this without using datapipeline?

Below is the csv foramte

Instance/Environment Name,Whitelisting End Date,Email
ABC258,1/19/2018,johndoe1@accenture.com
ABC259,1/19/2018,johndoe1@accenture.com

Comment: I think you should be able to do quite easily. Essentially, you'd need to ensure that Lambda has permissions to the s3 bucket, from there pull in the data with the aws-sdk. I think you'd need a csv parser  to parse the csv data from s3(note: any external dependencies outside aws-sdk, would require that you zip and upload your lambda function/package). After parsing the same, you can dump the data into Dynamo using the aws-sdk too.

Comment: Yes, you can do it very easily using AWS SDKs. If you're using Python, you'll want to check boto3 [Batch Writing](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/dynamodb.html) to improve performance in Dynamo writes.

Comment: Not as easy as you might think. Depending on how much data you have, you have to handle provisioned throughput exceeded errors. None of the examples seem to want to cover that. In fact, to do this properly, you should handle these errors regardless of the amount of data. Another alternative is AWS data pipeline which is designed for this sort of thing.